# Animate appended text

Tags: jquery

How would I got about animating appended text to a div tag. For eample the div starts out with no text in it. When a user clicks a button it apends text to the div which the div expands to the height of the text. Instead of just expanding instantly. I would like to animate the expand.

Would I first need to store the height of the div when the text is appended to the div. Then set the height of the div to 0 and then animate the height to the stored text height, or is there a more efficient way.

**Updated explanation** 
The text will populate about 4 lines in the div when added. Take 3 divs, a top div, center div which is my empty div waiting to be filled. Then a bottom div. With no text in my middle div it looks like the top and bottom div are close to each other. With 4 lines of text added to the middle div the bottom div instantly gets pushed down by the height of the new text in the middle div. I want to show this in animation as opposed to instantly happening.

Comment: Animating from no text to some text is quite trivial, however, animating from some text to more text is a bit trickier. Do you require both?

Comment: I would like to see how both are done if you have time. In my case I have an empty div to start out wit always, so it would be the easy approach as you mentioned.

Comment: Is this the effect you're going for: http://jsfiddle.net/mv3uC/2/?

Comment: Do you have a set width/height for the div that you're filling with the animated text?

Comment: g_thom you got it right nice thanks so much. kinakuta no the set height would be the dynamically added text height.

Answer (score 2):

If the div starts out with no text in it, then simply reveal it then slide it down once it has been filled with text. E.g.:

```
$("#myDiv").html(html).slideDown("slow");
```

assuming the div starts out hidden, such as:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

One suggestion: Don't animate the height, just animate the font size and let the height naturally grow to fit. Example:

```
<div></div>
<input>
<button>Add text</button>
```

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('div')
        .text($('input').val())
        .css({fontSize: 0})
        .animate({
            fontSize: "24px",
        });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UHcp6/

Really it depends on what exact behavior you want, this is just one way to do it.

Appending additional text afterwards seems like a bad case for animation, but if you want to append text, just store the original value in a variable with `text()`, then use `text(var + your_text)`.

Comment: Thanks Wesley but this wasn't quite what I had in mind. The txt will be on 4 different lines. So it will start out with no text inside the div. The the user clicks and the text is added. So it woild look like a box opening up to show the text inside it. like 2 shutters starting off in the center and then moving apart to reveal the text.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing it... You should definitely [add those details to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6965044/edit) though, it's a bit vague in it's current form.